# ComboBox isnt displaying information from database

Tags: c#

I have to create an automated teller machine app to access a database that contians sample customer records. I am having a problem displaying the account numbers from the accountInformation table (database), in my comboBox. I am pretty sure that I created the database connection correctly, and I thought that the code I have would dispay the numbers in the comboBox, so I'm not sure what the problem is. Is there something in comboBox properties that I need to change?
Here is my code:

```
using SQLDll;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication14
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Connection myConnection;
    private Statement myStatement;
    private ResultSet myResultSet;
    String databaseURL = "http://www.boehnecamp.com/phpMyAdmin/razorsql_mysql_bridge.php";


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            //connect to database
            SQL sql = new SQL();
            myConnection = sql.getConnection(databaseURL);
            //create Statement for executing SQL
            myStatement = myConnection.createStatement(databaseURL);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cannot connect to database server");
        }
        //close statement and database connection 
       myStatement.close();
       myConnection.close();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       loadAccountNumbers();
    }

    public void setText(string text)
    {


    }
    //load account numbers to ComboBox
    private void loadAccountNumbers()
    {
        //get all account numbers from database
        try
        {
            myResultSet = myStatement.executeQuery("SELECT accountNumber FROM accountInformation");
            // add account numbers to ComboBox
            while (myResultSet.next())
            {
                accountNumberComboBox.Items.Add(myResultSet.getString("accountNumber"));
            }
            myResultSet.close(); // close myResultSet
        }//end try
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error in loadAccountNumbers");
        }
    }//end method to loadAccountNumbers
```

Comment: What do you have myResultSet declared as?  (type, value, etc)

Comment: What happens when you step through your code? Do you ever enter the `while (myResultSet.next())` loop?

Comment: Depending on where or how you are calling the method you might have to insert a 'combobox.refresh()' after the method call.  Even if it is a single threaded program this can sometimes be the case- I experienced it in a project I was coding the other day.   And you should definitely just put breakpoints all over that loop and see if you're even hitting it.  The debugger is your friend!

Comment: private ResultSet myResultSet;

Comment: I'll try placing breakpoints throughout the loop and see what I find

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend putting everything in one method.  It is more readable and you can ensure everything gets closed even if an exception occurs.

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Connection myConnection;
    private Statement myStatement;
    private ResultSet myResultSet;
    String databaseURL = "http://www.boehnecamp.com/phpMyAdmin/razorsql_mysql_bridge.php";

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    loadAccountNumbers();
}

//load account numbers to ComboBox
private void loadAccountNumbers()
{
    SQL sql = new SQL();
    using (myConnection = sql.getConnection(databaseURL))
    using (myStatement = myConnection.createStatement(databaseURL))
    using (myResultSet = myStatement.executeQuery("SELECT accountNumber FROM accountInformation"))
    {
        // add account numbers to ComboBox
        while (myResultSet.next())
            accountNumberComboBox.Items.Add(myResultSet.getString("accountNumber"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that your code is more readable, but I wouldn't be meeting the "requirements" if I changed mine.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong. I knew I had to call loadAccountNumbers() somewhere but I wasn't sure where. I placed it in public Form1() and that fixed my problem! Thanks for all the help.